# Meaning of backslash in QgsExpression PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I m filtering using a `QgsExpression` :

```
filterexpression="\"date\"<='{}' AND \"date\">='{}'AND \"nom\"='{}' AND \"id_serie_type\"='{}'".format(date2,datee,nompointeau,serietype)
expr = QgsExpression( filterexpression )
```

I tried to make it work, but I do not understand what is the use of the backslash in my fields.

Comment: It escapes the following character " so that it doesn't terminate the filterexpression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user30184 said in comments, the backslashes are used to escape a character (here `"`). As the entire expression must be between quote (to be a python string) and you need double-quote in your expression (to declare fields here), you need to escape them.

An alternative solution could be to use three double quote for the python string:

```
filterexpression=""""date"<='{}' AND "date">='{}'AND "nom"='{}' AND "id_serie_type"='{}'""".format(date2,datee,nompointeau,serietype)
```

It works the exact same way but you don't need to escape the double-quote because you use """ to declare your python string.

You can learn more about strings in python in this [tutorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/python/getting-started/string/tutorial/) for example