# Calculate length of selected features in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, qgis-3, expression, length

I create a selection with `getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest())` and I want to calculate the length of the result which is a `QgsFeatureIterator` :

```
select = QgsExpression(" myexpression ")
selectedfeats = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(select ))

total = 0
for feature in selectedfeats :
    geom = feature.geometry()
    total += geom.length()
```

But it doesn't work it returns 0 whereas the `selectedfeats` is not empty.

Comment: There is no error in your code. Show how you create the layer and your expression

Comment: Possibly print a count of selectedfeats to insure it is not empty going into the for loop.  Your code is working correctly for me getting lengths of polylines in a layer.  Also - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299531/meaning-of-backslash-in-qgsexpression-pyqgis